# Android In-app billing getPurchaseHistory() doesn't work

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing

According to [in-app billing reference](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html) and [the next aidl definition](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl), there is method `getPurchaseHistory()`. The code is as simple as:

```
Bundle purchaseHistoryBundle = service.getPurchaseHistory(6, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, "subs", null, new Bundle());
```

Response I get is `6 (BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ERROR)`. That means "Fatal error during the API action"

What's wrong with the code? And if it is a bug in the service, where is the right place to report it?

Comment: Have you tried opening an issue [in here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new)?

Comment: @noogui yes, can be found here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37325333

Comment: Sorry for not answering your question, but can you please tell me how did you get this method? I can't call it anywhere, it's not even in IInAppBillingService.aidl from TrivialDrive sample app. I would need it too. Thanks

Comment: @BlackJack check out links I provided in question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try your code now. getPurchaseHistory() now works.